# Js приложение то работает то нет

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Есть приложение myeveryday.ru если на него зайтм вроде все работает, но если заходить периодически или перезагружать страницу то выдает ошибки, котопые я не понимаю, потом если снова перезагрузить ошибки пропадают.

Есть подозрение что это из за порядка подключения js фвйлов, но тогда непонятно почему оно всетаки иногда работает а иногда нет

Comment: `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bootstrap.min.css.map, line 0)` - вот единственная ошибка.

Comment: подозреваю - что ваши ошибки связаны с тем, что данные с подгрузки не успевают загружаться. В следствии чего, JavaScript не может выполнить операции с объектами тип которых `null`

Comment: Значит не может найти такой файл bootstrap.min.css.map

Comment: А что нужно сделать чтобы они успевали?

Comment: А бутстрап тогда лучше через cdn подключить?

Comment: Пробовать вызывать нужные методы внутри блока $(document).ready(function(){
  // your code
});

Comment: не думаю что JS не может выполнить какую то операцию, ведь судя по ошибке файл попросту не загружается из-за 404

уточните пожалуйста как отловить баг? на главной странице без авторизации просто иногда не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/view/common/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--bootstrap 3-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--шрифт -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/view/common/css/common.css?v1" />
  <!--общие стили-->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/view/common/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/view/todo_list/todo_list.css?v1" />
  <!--стили todo_list-->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Ежедневник EveryDay</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="black_fon"></div>

  <div class="container-fluid header clearfix">
    <!--шапка сайта-->
    <img src="/view/common/img/logo.svg" alt="Ежедневник EveryDay" />
    <div class="header_info clearfix">
      <a href="#"> Выход</a>
      <p>rpk54@yandex.ru</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid todo_list_content clearfix">


    <div class="row add_full_task popup" id="add_full_task">
      <!--полная форма добавления задачи-->
      <div class="back" iddiv="add_full_task">x</div>
      <h4>Добавить задачу</h4>
      <div class="row add_container">
        <div class=" change_option_window col-xs-12">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" opt="block_1" class="btn btn-default add_full_task_select">Опции</button>
            <button type="button" opt="block_2" class="btn btn-default add_full_task_select">Доп. опции</button>
            <button type="button" opt="block_3" class="btn btn-default add_full_task_select">Подзадачи</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div opt="block_1" class="col-xs-12 task_option  add_full_task_option">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Задача" />
          <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Описание" rows="2"></textarea>

          <div class="optionframe">
            <h5>Сроки</h5>
            <span>Дата: </span><input type="text" class="form-control start_date" placeholder="гггг-мм-дд" />
            <a href="#">диапазон...</a>
            <br>
            <span>Время: </span><input type="text" class="form-control start_time" placeholder="__:__" />
            <a href="#">диапазон...</a>
            <br>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>не повторять</option>
              <option>повторять каждый день</option>
              <option>повторять еженедельно</option>
              <option>повторять раз в месяц</option>
              <option>повторять раз в год</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end task_option основные опции-->
        <div opt="block_2" class="col-xs-12 task_else_option add_full_task_option">
          <div class="optionframe">
            <h5>Приоритет</h5>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>нет</option>
              <option>неважный</option>
              <option>средний</option>
              <option>важный</option>
              <option>сверхважный</option>
            </select>
            <h5>Контекст</h5>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>нет</option>
              <option>выезд</option>
              <option>звонок</option>
              <option>встреча</option>
              <option>за компьютером</option>
            </select>
            <h5>Адрес</h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Адрес" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end task_else_option дополнительные опции-->
        <div opt="block_3" class="col-xs-12 add_undertask add_full_task_option">
          <div class="optionframe clearfix">
            <h5>Добавить подзадачу</h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="подзадача" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="подзадача" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="подзадача" />
            <button type="button" class="btn add_undertask_btn">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end add_container-->

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Добавить</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Отмена</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="todo_list ">
      <!--контейнер со списком задач на выбранную дату-->
      <div class="block_header clearfix">
        <!--шапка контейнера с кнопками-->
        <p><span id="top_date">Текущая или выбранная дата</span></p>
        <div class="todo_buttons">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm substract_day_btn">
            <span class="btn_ico prev_ico"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm plus_day_btn">
            <span class="btn_ico next_ico"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm task_ico_btn open_popup" iddiv="add_full_task" title="Добавить задачу, группу задач">
            <span class=" task_ico"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm open_quick_task_block" lock="open" title="Добавить быструю задачу"><span
              class="btn_ico plus_ico"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-btn-default btn-sm">Меню </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end block_header-->

      <div class="add_quick_task ">
        <!--блок добавления быстрой задачи-->
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control quick_time" title="время в формате чч:мм" maxlength="5"
                placeholder="__:__" /></td>
            <td class="td_quick_name"><input type="text" class="form-control quick_name" placeholder="Быстрая задача" /></td>
            <td><button class="btn add_quick_btn"><span class="btn_ico plus_black_ico"></span></button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--end add_quick_task-->
      <div class="todo_content">
        <!--список задач по дате todoContent(task_list, todo_date)-->

        <ul class="hard_task list-group">
          <!--контейнер дляжесткихх задач listTask(task) todoContent(task_list, todo_date-->
        </ul>

        <ul class="flexible_task list-group">
          <!--контейнер для гибких задач listTask(task) todoContent(task_list, todo_date-->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--end todo_content-->
    </div>
    <!--end todo_list-->
    <div class="calendar_content">
      <!--блок с календарем-->
      <div class="block_header clearfix">
        <p>Календарь</p>
      </div>
      <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
    <!--end calendar-->
    <!--блок списка задач-->


  </div>
  <!--end todo_list_content-->



  <script src="/view/common/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" defer></script>
  <!--jquery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/view/common/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" defer></script>
  <!--jquery маска ввода-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/view/common/js/cookie.js" defer></script>
  <!--ФУНКЦИИ ДЛЯ КУК-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/view/common/js/common.js?v1" defer></script>
  <!--общие скрипты-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/view/common/js/calendar.js?v1" defer></script>
  <!--скрипт календаря-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/view/todo_list/js/todo_list_block.js?v1" defer></script>
  <!--скрипт todo_list-->
</body>

</html>
```

1. Best Practice это все ссылки на *js* файлы ставить в конец `<body>`
2. Во время тестирования заметил что вылетают ошибки по *javascript* иногда, и причиной этого является `async` для загрузки скриптов. Заменил на `defer`, чтобы гарантировать правильный порядок загрузки. [Детальнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script)

Comment: благодарю за помощь, вроде помогло, пока ошибок не вижу